# Google Cloud APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm new to google Cloud. I'm not sure if Google's Workload Identity Federation can be used if I want my Spring Boot application which is running outside the Google Cloud to access Google APIs such as Calendar API? Or it's only for Cloud Run or Google Kubernetes Engine clusters? What's the best solution for doing this in production environment without involving a Service Account access key?
**I don't want to use Service Account access key!**

I read about Application Default Credentials (ADS) approach involving the service account impersonation but it seems to be used only in development or testing environment.
I tried OAuth 2.0, but it's not suitable in my specific case. Because my application must not require users to grant access to their own Google Calendar data. Instead it's dealing only with my private Google Calendar data.
I thought about API keys it seems to be used for only accessing publicly available data anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar is part of google apis.  In order to access a private google calendar you need the permission of the owner of the calendar.

As you have seen Oauth2 grants your application access to a users google calendar account.

Service accounts require domain wide delegation to be used with Google workspace and google calendar.  You can then configure your code to allow the service account access to any users calendar on your workspace domain.   It does not work with standard gmail domain users calendars.

API keys, give you read only access **public data** only not private user data.  So if a google calendar was set to public then you could get read only access to it using an api key.

Those are your options which authorization method you should use will depend upon your use case.

1. Access user calendar use Oauth2
2. access calendars on Google workspace domain use service account.
3. access a public calendar read only use an API key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it didn’t answer to my main questions. How to implement authorization without a service account access key? Can workload identity federation be used if my case if the app is running outside the google cloud? What other authorization methods can be used with a service account for production environment?

Comment: My point is you have only two options if you want to access private user data you need to use Oauth2 or a service account.    Identity federation has nothing to do with access to google apis.   These are your only options. If you dont want to use a service account then use Oauth2 and request consent of the owner.